# How to solve vue bind by methods like this

Tags: vue.js

Look.

When `data_a` changes, `getDataB` will execute.

How to deal with this problem?

```
<template>
<div>
    <div :data-a="data_a">
        demo show params A
    </div>
    <div :data-b="getDataB()">
        demo show params B
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                data_a: 0,
                datas: [
                    0, 1, 2, 3, 4
                ]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getDataB () {
                console.log('getDataB() called');
            }
        },
        mounted () {
            setInterval(function () {
                this.data_a = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000000));
            }.bind(this), 1000);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Use `computed` instead of method then. Methods run on every re-render.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - switch to ES6 and avoid `bind`.

```
mounted () {
            setInterval( () => {
                this.data_a = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000000));
            }, 1000);
        }
```

Then modify getDataB to make it computed:

```
computed: {
            dataB () {
                // do something with data_a
                console.log('calc based on this.data_a in progress...')
                return this.data_a*2 // ;)
            }
        },
```